# Are dvmPauseGc and dvmResumeGc errors on Android important?

Tags: java, android, cordova

During startup of my `Android` app (`Cordova`, `PhoneGap`, `Java` and `JavaScript`), `logcat` shows these errors:

```
E/dalvikvm﹕ dvmPauseGc(AppLaunch) called - cookie=0xa028 (f=0x1)
E/dalvikvm﹕ dvmResumeGc(0xa028, 0) called (f=0x1)
```

All is working fine, but I don't know whether these errors are important (or not).

Thanks in advance